# Excel: Open Workbook in a new application does not run the Workbook_Open event

Tags: excel, vba

From the code of Excel A , I want to open Excel B.

Using this code, the new Excel is open in a new Excel Application, so you have 2 independent Excel windows, BUT! The Workbook_Open code of the sFileB is not executed:

```
Dim myApp As New Excel.Application
myApp.Workbooks.Open sFileB
myApp.Visible = True
```

If I open the new Excel inside the same application then I have only 1 Excel windows with the 2 files open, but opening the file in this way the Workbook_Open event is executed correctly:

```
Workbooks.Open sFileB
```

I want to open the new excel sFileB in a new application and, of course, I want to execute the Workbook_Open code of sFileB.
Do you know the reason of why in the first case the Workbook_Open is not executed? Any solution to force the execution of the event? Maybe I'm doing something wrong... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenXLFileInNewInstance()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, wb As Workbook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Tmp\xTemplate.xlsm")

    'wb.Close False
    'xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul's answer, I could do some more testing and discovered that the point is to write FIRST the line **myApp.Visible = True** before the line **myApp.Workbooks.Open sFileB**.

So this is the definitive working code:

```
Set myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myApp.Visible = True
myApp.Workbooks.Open sFileB
```